# How would I get it to add the File Creation time to my .txt name?

Tags: c#, date, text, stamp

I am creating multiple .txt files for my DataGridView and I wanted to add a creation date to them.
*****EDIT*****
I have changed my code to the following to see if it would output a time stamp:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime timenow = new DateTime();
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyddhh");
    Console.WriteLine(timenow.ToString());

    string LPath = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".txt");

    using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(LPath, true))
    {
        string LContent = textName.Text + "," + textVehicle.Text + "," + textDurationH.Text + " " + textDurationM.Text + "," + textFreight.Text + "," + textWeight.Text + "," + textIncome.Text + "," + LPath;
        objWriter.Write(LContent);
        infoTabelle.Rows.Add(LContent.Split(','));
        objWriter.WriteLine();
    }
    replace();
}
```

But it just outputs 01.01.0001 00:00:00.
What do I have to do? :/

---

I have tried using various DateTime commands but none have seemed to work for me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyddhh");` is not doing anything. Did you mean to assign it to a variable?

Comment: OH ok so thats me problem then.
It gives output in the Console but its not correct. How would I need to rewrite my code in order to save it with that date-timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
```

instead of

```
DateTime timenow = new DateTime();
```

Then add it to your filename string.

Comment: I tried doing so, but it gives me a System.NotSupportedException Error now.

Comment: I mistype sorry. I edited the answer and removed the "new" from DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;

Comment: Ok so that command without the new is giving me a correct time, but it gives me a System.NotSupportedException Error at this line:

            using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(LPath, true))